# What's the point of declaring a general practitioner ("médecin traitant") in France?

Tags: france, health-care, health-system

What are the financial consequences not to declare a general practitioner ("médecin traitant") in France? I have a French Social Security as well as a French "mutuel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a “médecin traitant”, there is a financial penalty. Physicians are allowed to charge more (*dépassement d'honoraire*), the statutory health insurance will only offer reduced coverage and the *mutuelle* should not cover the difference.

The idea is that you should get a referral from your GP before going to other medical professionals (it's called *parcours de soins coordonnés*, see [service-public.fr](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F10870.xhtml) and [ameli.fr](http://www.ameli.fr/assures/soins-et-remboursements/comment-etre-rembourse/le-parcours-de-soins-coordonnes/objectif-des-soins-coordonnes_rhone.php)). There are exceptions, though: family planning, addiction treatment, emergencies, etc.